# Request available for Angular but not for web browser

Tags: angularjs, json, http, express

I've just started learning web development. Sorry if there is similiar question, but I couldn't find the satisfying answer. I'm trying to perform a simple http get request from angular to obtain a simple json response. However I can manually type `localhost:8080/test` and the json is rendered on my screen. Is there any standard solution for getting information from server with angular? I believe in normal application I shouldn't be able to see this json directly. I have:

`controllers.js`

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp',[]);

myApp.controller('myController', function($scope, $http) {
    $http.get('/test').success(function(data) {
        $scope.greeting = data.test;
    });        
})
```

in `server.js`

```
app.get('/test', function(req, res) {
    res.status(200).json({'test': 'it works!'});
})
```

Comment: Well, the code works. I asked how to let angular get something from server but dont let user get raw json by typing proper url.

Comment: however your question is still not much clear but according to me you could do it by placing any anchor tag over it so whenever any user clicks. You will get data on screen. And Display data to user in json format isn't best practice. hence convert it to array/string then display over html/jade/ejs whatever you're on with.

Comment: As far as I understand websites with angular are lightweight because server doesn't have to pass whole page as a request. Let's say server returns the page and then user clicks on some button and client needs some info from server. So I've read that server should answer angular with json. Then angular can update data. In my controller this is `$scope.greeting = data.test`. But with my current solution user can just type in url bar `server_adress/test` and he gets json as well. I don't want this to happen. I want my server answer at `/test` only when angular calls it.

Comment: ohk,..... now i'm clear with your question i think. So you should restrict user from accessing server_path/test in route configuration of your controller. And when you want the data to be displayed just send XHR request like this $http.get('/test').then().... and you're done with it.. Hope this time it helps

Comment: You got the point. I still don't know how to on the one hand restrict user in route configuration and on the other hand pass json when XHR arrives. Could you post any snippet.

Comment: Ok I've got it. Needed to add `$httpProvider.defaults.headers.common['X-Requested-With'] = 'XMLHttpRequest';` in my angular module config. And `req.xhr` check on the server. Thank you evry much =)

Comment: wait i'm posting an snippet

Comment: Can't wait to see it :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', ['ngRoute']);

myApp.config(['$routeProvider', '$locationProvider', function ($routeProvider, $locationProvider) {

    $routeProvider
        .when('/', {
            templateUrl: '/home',
            controller:'homeCtrl'
        })
        .when('/test', {
            templateUrl: '/test',
            controller:'errorCtrl'
        })
        .otherwise('/')
}]);
```

Now you've restricted user from visiting /test page.Then look here :

```
myApp.controller('homeCtrl', function ($scope) {
    $scope.getData = function(){
        $http.get('/test').then(function success(response){
           $scope.data = response.data;
         }, function error(error){
          console.log(error);
       });
    }
});

smpApp.controller(errorCtrl', function ($scope, $location) {
   $location.path('/home');
});
```

Now in Html like this :

```
<button type="button" ng-click="getData()">Get Data to user</button>
```

In Server.Js File

```
app.get('/test', function(req, res) {
   var data = {
     test : 'it works.fine !!!!'
   };
   res.json(data);
})
```

I hope you got the point....

**Thanks & Cheers**